# Python, working with list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have such code:

```
a = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

I want to get two lists, the first contains elements of `'a'`, where `a[][1] = 1`, and the second - elements where `a[][1] = 0`. So

```
first_list = [[1, 1], [2, 1]] 

second_list = [[3, 0]].
```

I can do such thing with two list comprehension:

```
first_list = [i for i in a if i[1] == 1]

second_list = [i for i in a if i[1] == 0]
```

But maybe exists other (more pythonic, or shorter) way to do this? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List comprehension are very pythonic and the recommended way of doing this. Your code is fine.

Comment: Agreed. There are 2 distinct lists/data sets, therefore 2 separate comprehensions should be used.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have it in a single line you could do something like

```
first_list, second_list = [i for i in a if i[1] == 1], [i for i in a if i[1] == 0]
```

Remember that, "Explicit is better than implicit."

Your code is fine

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sorted()` and `itertools.groupby()` to do this, but I don't know that it would qualify as Pythonic per se:

```
>>> dict((k, list(v)) for (k, v) in itertools.groupby(sorted(a, key=operator.itemgetter(1)), operator.itemgetter(1)))
{0: [[3, 0]], 1: [[1, 1], [2, 1]]}
```

Comment: Seems more complicated than just using the comprehensions? But I love the use of itertoos so +1

Comment: More complicated, certainly. But as the number of things you want to do with the data grows the faster this solution becomes, relatively speaking.

Comment: Just as a side note whats operator for?

Answer (score 0):

what about this,

```
In [1]: a = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 0]]

In [2]: first_list = []

In [3]: second_list = []

In [4]: [first_list.append(i) if i[1] == 1 else second_list.append(i) for i in a]
Out[4]: [None, None, None]

In [5]: first_list, second_list
Out[5]: ([[1, 1], [2, 1]], [[3, 0]])
```

instead of two sublist, I prefer dict (or defaultdict, OrderedDict, Counter, etc.)

```
In [6]: from collections import defaultdict

In [7]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [8]: [d[i[1]].append(i) for i in a]
Out[8]: [None, None, None]

In [9]: d
Out[9]: {0: [[3, 0]], 1: [[1, 1], [2, 1]]}
```

Comment: Using list comprehensions strictly for side effects is anti-Pythonic.

Comment: @lgnacio, agree, sometimes it maybe more readable without list comprehension(replace it with some for loop style)

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are reasonably short then two list comprehensions will do fine: you shouldn't be worried about performance until your code is all working and you know it is too slow.

If your lists are long or the code runs often **and** you have demonstrated that it is a bottleneck then all you have to do is switch from list comprehensions to a for loop:

```
first_list, second_list = [], []
for element in a:
    if element[1] == 1:
        first_list.append(element)
    else:
        second_list.append(element)
```

which is both clear and easily extended to more cases.

Answer (score 0):

list comprehensions are great. If you want slightly more simple code (but slightly longer) then just use a for loop.

Yet another option would be filters and maps:

```
a = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
g1=filter(lambda i: i[1]==1,a)
g1=map(lambda i: i[0],g1)
g2=filter(lambda i: i[1]==0,a)
g2=map(lambda i: i[0],g2)
print g1
print g2
```